# Find last pattern in variable text segments

Tags: regex

I need a find any pattern after the second or last dot in my string and before the ending curly bracet, e.g. @{image.imagetext} here the of the named group (action) should be empty and in @{image.imagetext.NoHtml} (i got many actions like NoHtml) here the result of the named group should be NoHtml.

Comment: Did you make any attempt?

Comment: Yes, i think i got it now: (?<tag>@{(?<tagname>(?:[^\.]*(?:\.[^\.]*)+))(?<action>(?:\.)[^}]*)?})

Comment: The new edited version gives "xy" in the action group

Comment: Please put code examples and suchlike in the body of your question as an edit rather than leaving them in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match action part that is after last DOT provided there are 2 DOTS before.

```
(?<tag>@{(?<tagname>[^.]+)\.(?:[^.}]*\.)+(?<action>[^.}]+)})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ii0jmO/1)

Comment: Is it possible to expand the tagname group to contain all characters except the content of the action group ?

Comment: I like your regex solution a lot, but i seem not quite there yet. First it does not match the @{image.imagepath} pattern and the ending dot should not be in the tag group.

Comment: You can try this regex: [`@{(?<tag>(?<tagname>[^.]+)\.(?:[^.}]*\.)*?[^.}]*)\.?(?<action>[^.}]*)}`](https://regex101.com/r/Ii0jmO/5)

Comment: Removing the ending dot in the tag group then i would have all the correct group values it need. I've change the regex a bit,  but still kept most of your regex. My current regex: @{(?<tag>[^.]+\.(?<tagname>(?:[^.}]*)\.)+)(?<action>[^.}]+)}

Comment: But that won't match `@{image.imagetext}` line which is matching in my regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is my wanted regex

```
(?<tag>@{(?<tagname>(?:[^\.]*(?:\.[^\.]*)+))(?:(?:\.)(?<acti‌​on>[^}]*))})
```

Comment: [Check your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ii0jmO/3) that will be very slow (368 steps vs 107 steps as in my regex)